# Extract text from MS Word table without bullets [Powershell 4.0]

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to extract some text from a ms word, from some particular table:
[image: table and text]

However, when I execute code:

```
$objWord = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$objWord.Visible = $true
$filename = 'D:\test.docx'
$objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open($filename)
$LETable = $objDocument.Tables.Item(1)
$LETableCols = $LETable.Columns.Count
$LETableRows = $LETable.Rows.Count

Write-output "Starting to write... "

$content2 = $LETable.Cell(6,2).Range.Text
$content3 = $LETable.Cell(7,1).Range.Text
$content4 = $LETable.Cell(7,2).Range.Text
#Write-host $content2
$doc2 = $objWord.Documents.Add()
$objWord.Selection.typetext("$content2")
$objWord.Selection.typetext("$content3")
$objWord.Selection.typetext("$content4")
#$objDocument.Close()
#$objWord.Quit()
# Stop Winword Process
#$rc = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objWord)
```

[image: bullets - question marks]

How to remove those bullets-questionmarks? I want just plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to find unicode expression for this character.Once found then use of regular expression can be helpful to replace it with empty character, space or tab.
I even try with "direct" copy and paste of "✀" and it works as well.

To remove character:
     $String -replace '✀'

to replace it:

```
 $String = "Just ✀ and another ✀"
#replace ✀ with cat
 $String -replace '✀','cat'
```

Ant the result is:

```
Just cat and another cat
```

Comment: and if I want to extract data from Word Table.Cell and for each line on newline (`r`n) to add "* "? I've tried with `$LETable.Cell(7,1).Range.Text -replace '\r\a','' -creplace '(?m)^\s*\r?\n','' | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($SearchText in $SearchArray) {
        $_.Range.Text | ForEach-Object {
             "* "+$_  | Select-Object -Last 1
        }
    }
}` Thanks

Comment: @Stefan0309 If his suggestion worked, you should upvote and mark the answer, so he can get the reward.

Comment: @Stefan0309 It is easier to use RegEx for each text block like this:

$text -replace '\r\n',"`r`n* "

That code will replace each new line with new line starting with asterisk and space (* ). The " in replacement part are very important!

Comment: Sorry, but just realize that i forgot the escaping character on previews comment. The correct example showed be:
`$text -replace '\r\n',"\`r\`n* "`
whit back ticks (`) before r and n

Comment: Unfortunately, no, that isnt quite good..I have on the last line "*".

Answer (score 0):

What you need in actual is to get the plain text of the document. 
Check out [Open-Xml-PowerTools](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools).

As docx files are open xml format, you can take advantage of this tool and its powerful commands.